# Trying to update two tables at once MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, relation

I've been trying make my database work so that `cuisineid` columns in different tables are linked together. I've got as far as defining the Primary and Foreign Keys on the two tables but when I try and update them now I get this error:

```
Insert failed: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`ml11maj_Databasetest`.`Nation`, CONSTRAINT `Foreign Key` FOREIGN KEY (`cuisineid`) 
REFERENCES `recipename` (`cuisineid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

The rest of the upload works, but nothing is added into the `Nation`(cuisine id is the primary key and currently set to AI) table, the code to insert currently looks like this

```
if ($cuisine !=''){
  $query = "INSERT INTO`Nation`(cuisine_type)VALUES('$cuisine')";
  mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database); 
  mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or
  die("Insert failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));
}
```

EDIT
Nation Table Contains two columns

-Cuisine_type Varchar
-cuisineid int Primary

The recipename table

-recipeid   int(255) AUTO_INCREMENT 
-mealname   text
-b_l_d  varchar(30) 
-ingredients    text
-hours  int(11)
-minutes    int(11)
-recipe text    utf8_bin
-feeds  int(11)
-imagepath  varchar(100)
-userid int(11)
-cuisineid  int(255)

Comment: You're inserting a `cuisine_type` and no `cuisine_id`

Comment: Please post the definitions of your `Nation` table and any other tables with interlocking keys.

Comment: i've updated the questions with my table definitions
cuisineid is an auto-incrementing in the Nation table so how can I include this in my query?

Answer (score 0):

Your insert does not have a cuisine_id, so the foreign key constraint fails, as it tells you. If you want that column to be NULLABLE then you can omit the cuisine_id column in your insert.

Comment: im confused as cuisineid is an auto incrementing column in Nation so I cant define a variable for it

Comment: Then you put your FK on the wrong table, because you have it set up to say nation.cuisine_id should reference a primary key in the recipename table.

Comment: when i try and change the FK on the other table i get this error?

`#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ml11maj_Databasetest`.`#sql-5a08_197ee`, CONSTRAINT `Foreign Key` FOREIGN KEY (`cuisineid`) REFERENCES `Nation` (`cuisineid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)`

Comment: That looks like you are doing it right now, make sure the columns are exactly the same in size, type, unsigned, etc. Also make sure there are no rows in recipename that have an invalid cuisineid

Comment: I have now correctly defined keys now on phpmyadmin but when i try and upload i'm still getting the same error 

Insert failed. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ml11maj_Databasetest`.`recipename`, CONSTRAINT `Foreign Key` FOREIGN KEY (`cuisineid`) REFERENCES `Nation` (`cuisineid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: i've given up on this cannot find a fix.